# Looking for cheap cloud data storage option with virtual drive

Tags: windows, cloud-service, cloud-storage, virtualization

Does anyone know of a cheap ~ 1TB cloud service that includes virtual drive software such that I can mount the cloud drive as a local hard drive through Windows?

Comment: I think there is no cloud service that offers 1 TB of storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/):

- 1 TB for $9.99 a month.
- can [map a drive letter to Google Drive in Windows](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-map-a-drive-letter-to-google-drive-in-windows/)

Comment: the price is for **personal use**.  [Business pricing](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1726914) is different, 1TB costs **$89 a month**.

Comment: @miroxlav Thanks, good point! Though anyway 1 TB is not enough for my personal use ;)